# Is it possible to run a filter or sort on a map contained in a specific dynamodb record, when accessing the record from Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a record in dynamoDB that is structured like this

```
{
  "object_id": {
    "S": "users.notifications.{uid}"
  },
  "notifications": {
    "M": {
      "1682360554277": {
        "M": {
          "body": {
            "S": "test_body"
          },
          "heading": {
            "S": "test_heading"
          },
          "timestamp": {
            "N": "1682360554277"
          }
        }
      },
      "1682360555921": {
        "M": {
          "body": {
            "S": "test_body"
          },
          "heading": {
            "S": "test_heading"
          },
          "timestamp": {
            "N": "1682360555921"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "owner": {
    "S": "users.notifications"
  }
}
```

When using the Node AWS-SDK is it possible run some type of filter expression that will sort the notifications map by the time stamps in each record in the map? Ideally, I would like to only pull the records in the last 30 days. I am not sure if this is possible though from what I googled. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would likely not work how you would like:

```
FilterExpression: "notifications.1682360554277.timestamp > (30days) AND notifications.1682360555921.timestamp > (30days)"
```

It would be better if you vertically sharded your items and had individual item for each notification, which would allow you to Query it more efficiently.

Comment: I think you are right. I need to store each notification as their own record. Thank you!